# How to execute a server side script/application from a webapp

Tags: javascript, python, web, web-applications

So I'm writing a webapp for editing config files.

I already have a suite of python programs that can be adapted to this need on the server.

So my question is how could I execute these from the webpage apache is serving up?

I have already looked into pico but lack of examples and documentation meant I couldn't get even their hello world working.

Bonus points if I don't have to have a web-server backend (I.e just using apache) like node.js/pico listening 24/7 (this app is for silly windows admins who don't like to ssh into machines)

Comment: How do you expect a webapp to function without a webserver? If the pico docs were incomplete, you might want to check out some other minimalist python webframework such as Flask, which has a larger user base and better documentation.

Comment: thank I will, and I'm not a webdev, and by webserver I mean node.js n suchs, NOT apache (I may be dumb, but I'm not THAT dumb)

Comment: Writing apps for admins is as backwards as it gets. Write them a script that does 1. scp file to local 2. open it in notepad. 3. scp file back

Comment: I recommend reading through the flask quickstart guide for a overview of how a python webapp works. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/ Also read the section about deployment on a server. It's not that complicated once you understand how it works.

Comment: @Muposat I know its backwards, I have a python script that does EVERYTHING they would want, but these admins don't want to be bothered to SSH into it, and due to firewall rules and such I can't open sockets in java or python.